# Overloading comparison for double to allow for numerical error

Tags: c++, double, numeric

In my C++ project I frequently encounter inexact results due to numerical errors.  Is it somehow possible to somehow redefine the standard comparison operators (`==`, `<=`, `>=`, `<`, `>`) so that they do not compare exactly but within an acceptable error (e.g. `1e-12`) ?

(If yes, is it a good idea to do this?)

(Of course one could write comparison functions but people intuitively use the operators.)

Comment: You can't overload operators on builtin types, you need classes for that.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to change the semantics of operators for existing types which aren't yours.

Comment: Even if it had been possible, I can't imagine what kind of opeators you might use (except those obviously) to get the behaivour you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To overload operators some argument must be user-defined type. The built-in ones are fixed and unchangeable.

But even if you could it would hardly be a good thing. Do yourself a favor, and provide your custom compare "operators" as a set of functions, choosing a name that implies the strategy they use.   You can't expect a code reader to know without proper indication that equal means strict or with DBL_EPSILON or 2*DBL_EPSILON or some arbitrary linear or scaled tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload the operators for standard types (`int`, `float`, `char`, etc)

You could of course declare a type:

```
class Float
{
    private:
       float f;
    public:
       Float(float v) : f(v) {} 
       ... bunch of other constructors. 
       friend bool operator==(Float &a, Float &b);
       ... more operators here.
       float operator float() { return f; }
};

bool operator==(Float &a, Float &b) { return (fabs(b.f-a.f) < epsilon); }
bool operator==(Float &a, const float &b) { return (fabs(b-a.f) < epsilon); }
       ... several other operator declarations - need on also make operator
```

(The above code is "as an idea", not tested and perhaps need more work to be "good").

You would of course then need some ugly typedef or macro to replace "float" with "Float" everywhere in the code.

Comment: But you are still using the standart operators to write this code. Doesn't this mean that the new overloaded one will have the same bias when it comes to float\double?

Comment: Yes, I think the OP wanted just to over-ride the behaviour of `if (x == y) ...` failing because `x-y` is a very small value. The common solution for this is to compare with an `epsilon` value, which provides a "if the difference is smaller than this, we accept it as equal". Implementing your own, whole new floating point arithmetic would probably be no more accurate [unless you have studied the subject for MANY years], and certainly a lot slower [regardless of how much you've studied, because processor instructors take longer than microcode/hardcoded instructions].

Comment: Notice that your Float class now violates properties usually expected of the comparison operators. That means you can't use it for standard containers and algorithms where < has to define a strict weak ordering, and where == has to be relexive, symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot overload operators for built-in types.
No, changing the semantics of operators is (in general) not a good idea.

You could either:

- Use comparison-functions (as you suggest yourself).
- Write a wrapper-class around a `double` member that has the operators you want.